# Finding a Basis of a Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently taking a module on Partial Differential Equations, and whilst working through some exercises in the lecture notes, I come across the following question about a basis. My Linear Algebra skills seem to be a bit rusty, and although I know what the definition of basis, I cannot seem to use it in context and find a basis for this vector space. The question is as follow:

"Show that the solutions of the differential equation $u'''-3u''+4u=0$ form a vector space. Find a basis of it."

I am able to solve the ode and get that $u(t) =c_1e^{-t}+c_2e^{2t}+tc_3e^{2t}$ and from this I can use the vector space axioms to prove that this set of solutions is in fact a vector space, but how do I go about finding a basis for this vector space.

Thanks

Comment: Your solution does not seem to be correct.

Comment: finding a subset of this space that spans.... what? perhaps i didn't read carefully enough, but i didn't get that on the first two passes.

Comment: $\{e^{-t}, e^{2t}, te^{2t}\}$ would be the obvious choice of a basis.  Every solution is a linear combination of those 3 elements.  This is not the only way to form a basis.  Now, if you want to be thorough, show that this fits the definition of a vector space, and that that they are independent.

Comment: That seems remarkably simple and makes a lot of sense. I think I am over complicating it in my head. Thank you very much

Comment: Sorry, you were right, I had a mistake. Sorry for my mistake. I delete my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find a minimal set of functions such that any solution to this differential equation can be written as a linear combination of elements of this set. Indeed,
$$\{e^{-t},e^{2t}, te^{2t}\}$$
does the trick. First, based on what the general solution looks like, you can definitely write any solution as a linear combination of these three functions. Further, these three functions are linearly independent (as can be seen from computing the Wronskian), and so they form a basis of the solution space.